# writing c++ installer files

Tags: linux, c++11

My have written a function definition in c++ which I want to use in other c++ projects. In a typical way we include .hpp files in the header

```
#include "my_fun.hpp"
```

I don't want to copy each time this file to the right location. What I want is to install this .hpp on my linux machine so that I can type

```
#include <my_fun>
```

How to write installer files on linux for c++ project? You know, not just on my machine, but any other person equipped with those files can install and use my function (like a library).

Comment: What build-system do you use? CMake and Autotools can help you installing the headers.

Comment: I am a freshman in this topic. Maybe I will just put .hpp file in /usr/include. I thought that some application can do this for me and print an alert if some libraries are not present etc.

Comment: I advice you to have look at CMake. If you don't have a build system yet, you should definitely start using one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy your header to `/usr/local/include`.  That way it will be included by default, and it will not get mixed in with the headers installe by your package manager to `/usr/include`.

Comment: Maybe it is better to put it into a subfolder of /usr/local/include. Otherwise you might run into naming conflicts.